# What is the best way to delete nested Python dictionary Keys and it's curely braces?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

all I have a JSON file loaded as a dictionary via json.loads:

```
dict = {
 "Area":[
  {
    "id": "aira-01",
    "vis": [
     "menu"
     "hamburger"
     ]
  },
  {
    "id": "aira-02"
  }
```

The objective is to delete the entire key and value: "id": "aira-02". Since it is a nested dictionary, i wrote this snippet to access:

```
    for i in range(len(dict["Area"])):
        if dict["Area"][i]["id"] == "aira-02":
           del dict["Area"][i]["id"]
```

The end result is "id": "aira-02" is removed but it got a set of remaining curly braces { } that I would also like to remove. Below is how the code looks like when "id": "aira-02" is removed but not the curly braces:

```
"Area":[
  {
    "id": "aira-01",
    "vis": [
     "menu"
     "hamburger"
     ]
  },
  {}
```

Also since "id": "aira-02" is supposed to be removed, the remaining "id": "aira-01" should not end with a comma. The version below is what the end product should look like:

```
dict = {
 "Area":[
  {
    "id": "aira-01",
    "vis": [
     "menu"
     "hamburger"
     ]
  }
```

What is the best approach to handle this? Should convert the dictionary to string and remove the braces as well as the comma?

Thank you

Comment: Why shouldn't the remaining `id` have a trailing comma, as appears in your example of what the end result should be?

Comment: You'll need to add additional code to remove empty dictionaries from `dict['Area']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove items from a list it more efficient to create a new list by filter out unwanted items instead:

```
d['Area'] = [i for i in d['Area'] if i['id'] != 'aira-02']
```

Note that you should avoid naming your variable `dict`, which would shadow the built-in name. The example above uses the name `d` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your input. What is the name of this technique? I would like to read more about it

Comment: You're welcome. This is called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in Python.